# Making a Map or a List observable in Web UI

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I can make a String or a num type observable by using the @observable declaration in the Dart code:

```dart
@observable
var x = '';
```

and `{{   }}` syntax in the html:

```dart
<div>x = {{x}}</div>
```

But `@observable` does not work with Lists and Maps. How do I make those observable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `toObservable()` with the List or Map as an argument. This creates a 
binding between the List or Map object and its representation in the UI.

The following example uses `toObservable()`. Notice that the List and Map
objects have data added to them every second. With `toObservable()` creating
the proper binding, the UI for these objects auto-magically updates to show 
the added items.

When the List or Map are `clear()`ed, the the UI once again reflects this.

For instructions on how to build and run a script such as this one, see 
http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/tools.html.

Here is the `main.dart` file:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

@observable
num x = 0;  // @observable works fine with a number. 

List list = toObservable(new List());

Map<String, num> map = toObservable(new Map());

void main() {
   new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
     x += 1;
     list.add(x);
     map[x.toString()] = x;
     if (x % 4 == 0) {
       list.clear();
       map.clear();
     }
     return x;
   });
}
```

And here is the accompanying `dart.html` file:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
     <p>x = {{ x }}</p>

     <ul>
       <template iterate='item in list'>
         <li>list item = {{item}}</li>
       </template>
     </ul>

     <ul>
       <template iterate='key in map.keys'>
         <li>map key = {{key}}, map value = {{map[key]}}</li>
       </template>
     </ul>

    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```