# dart web component don't refresh a List on UI

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I'm trying to create a simple web component which purpose is to display messages for some seconds and then dissapear. I've got displayed the first two Strings but when I call the informar method nothing happens:

```dart
<element name="x-informador" constructor="InformadorComponente" extens="div">
      <template>
        <ul>
          <template iterate="mensaje in mensajes">
            <li>{{mensaje}}</li>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </template>
      <script type="application/dart">

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
import 'package:web_ui/watcher.dart' as watcher;

class InformadorComponente extends WebComponent {

  @observable
  List mensajes = ['uno', 'dos'];

  const int DURACION_MENSAJE = 7;

  void informar(String informe) {
    mensajes.add(informe);
    watcher.dispatch();

    print('antes del Timer: ');
    print(mensajes);

    new Timer(new Duration(seconds: DURACION_MENSAJE), () {
      mensajes.removeAt(0);
      watcher.dispatch();

      print('paso del mensajes, first');
      print(mensajes);
    });
  }
}
      </script>
    </element>
```

I can see all those prints correctly on my browser, but the list remains the same, nothing happens. When I change that list for a String and assign values when calling the informar method UI is refreshed but when I use this list, nothing.

Browser don't show any error and I'm calling informar from outside, from a web component up on the herarchy.

Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Making a Map or a List observable in Web UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814349/making-a-map-or-a-list-observable-in-web-ui).

Basically, you want to use the new (and so far, mostly undocumented) `toObservable()` function to make Lists observable.  Observables are displacing watcher.dispatch() as the preferred way of watching objects for changes.