# template is not auto-binding

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm trying to startup a Dart Polymer project using the pub pacakage manager. I'm using Eric Bidelman's [scaffolding page example](http://polymer-change.appspot.com/demos/spa.html) as an example because it's quite what I need. . And while I have added the

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
```

it still will throw the following error on the is="autobinding"-attribute of the template element:

```dart
custom element with name "auto-binding" not found. See http://goo.gl/5HPeuP#polymer_11 for details.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction because as far as I can see in the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding) of the auto-binding property a polymer.html import is sufficient for the is-attribute to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart the equivalent element is `auto-binding-dart` instead of `auto-binding`. See [Data binding fails with Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497845) for an example.